# Error al inicializar conexion libreoffice Calc con Oracle Forms 6i

Tags: oracle

Estimados tengo un problema al querer realizar la impresión de reportes con LibreCalc utilizando oracle forms, que valores les debo poner en el campo de DDE.inicializate(tema, topic)??